# Why did NASA's Soujourner Mars rover die at the same time as Pathfinder?

Tags: mars, opportunity, spirit

The Soujourner rover operated with the Pathfinder lander, but when pathfinder's mission was declared to be completed, the rover's was too. Why?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The only way for the Soujourner rover to transmit data to Earth or receive commands from Earth was through the Pathfinder lander. If Pathfinder died, Sojourner was also essentially dead.

Comment: So, in theory, could a new device be sent to Mars (either an orbiter or a lander) to the last known general location of Sojourner, to take the place of the defunct Pathfinder as a transmitting relay?  (Not asking if it'd be worth the effort, just if it'd be possible...)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Not likely. The rover is almost certainly dead by now -- and almost certainly nearly useless as well. That was 25 years ago, meaning many dust storms rained dust on it. Moreover, it was very light on capability.

Comment: @DavidHammen Well, we could send Mark Watney to fix it (and put it to good use) :-)

Comment: @TooTea, yup, just give him enough potatoes and he'll get the job done.

Comment: poopy potatoes.